# Password validator is not working in android

Tags: android, regex, validation, passwords

In my application I am accepting a password from the user which should be in following format:-

- case sensitive and
- must be at least 6 characters long,
- including at least

  - one letter (a-Z),
  - one number (0-9) and
  - one of the following special characters:!=+*;:-,._{[()]}#%?@

So by following the tutorial given here: 
http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-password-with-regular-expression/
I have created my own pattern as:-

```
private static final String PASSWORD_PATTERN = "($\\S*(?=\\S{6,})(?=\\S*[a-z])(?=\\S*[A-Z])(?=\\S*[\\d])(?=\\S*[\\W])\\S*$)";
```

But it is not working properly. If I enter a correct value for the password as per pattern, it still displays an error to me.

Please tell me what's happening here; what error is there?

Here is my code:-

```
 PWD_Validate = new PasswordValidator();
    String password = TXT_PassWord.getText().toString();

   if (PWD_Validate.validate(password))
            {
            }                                                                                         
                                                                                                         else{                                                                                       }                                                                                            it takes me every time in else block, even I entered a correct passwaord.
```

Comment: post your code please

Comment: Hi Aniruddha, PasswordValidatorTest class is same as given on link, just replace the password_pattern string with my given string above.   And rest in my activity I am validating on button click as given above. i have posted my code above.

Comment: I want to know how you are getting the value from edittext.

Comment: Hi I have posted the code for that, please check

Comment: When are you taking the value from edittext? On click of button?

Comment: Yes i am taking the value on click of button at validating also.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you've deviated from the pattern that is listed within the tutorial you've linked. Your pattern starts with `$` which asserts position at end of the string, so it's highly unlikely you'll match anything. Usually if you're using an assertion you use `$` at the very end of the pattern and `^` to assert the beginning.

Also no where in your pattern do you have any of the special characters you've outlined as those you've said are required. If you plan on matching those I would recommend including them into your pattern.

The breakdown of your regex goes like this:

`$` assert position at end of the string (you've got it at the beginning).

`\S*` match any non-white space character `[^\r\n\t\f ]`
Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

`(?=\S{6,})` Positive Lookahead - Assert that the regex below can be matched

`\S{6,}` match any non-white space character `[^\r\n\t\f ]`
 Quantifier: Between 6 and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

`(?=\S*[a-z])` Positive Lookahead - Assert that the regex below can be matched

`\S*` match any non-white space character `[^\r\n\t\f ]`
Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

`[a-z]` match a single character present in the list below
 a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)

`(?=\S*[A-Z])` Positive Lookahead - Assert that the regex below can be matched

`\S*` match any non-white space character `[^\r\n\t\f ]`
Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

`[A-Z]` match a single character present in the list below

`A-Z` a single character in the range between A and Z (case sensitive)

`(?=\S*[\d])` Positive Lookahead - Assert that the regex below can be matched

`\S*` match any non-white space character `[^\r\n\t\f ]`
Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

`[\d]` match a single character present in the list below
 \d match a digit [0-9]

`(?=\S*[\W])` Positive Lookahead - Assert that the regex below can be matched

`\S*` match any non-white space character `[^\r\n\t\f ]`
Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

`[\W]` match a single character present in the list below
 \W match any non-word character `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`

`\S*` match any non-white space character `[^\r\n\t\f ]`
Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

`$` assert position at end of the string

> To be quite honest your regex is so far off from the tutorial you've
>   linked that it's not even remotely close. I would recommend you go
>   back and thoroughly re-read and study the guide, for it's apparent you
>   haven't applied any of it to be applicable by any means.